# Where do I put common development methods for rspec and rake in my gem file tree?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Here is current gem structure:

```
├── Gemfile
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── mygem.gemspec
├── images
│   ├── 1b1d4bde376084011d027bba1c047a4b.jpg
│   ├── 1d468d064d2e26b5b5de9a0241ef2d4b.jpg
│   ├── 309666c7b45ecbf8f13e85a0bd6b0a4c.jpg
│   ├── 3f9f3db06db20d1d9f8188cd753f6ef4.jpg
│   ├── 679634ff89a31279a39f03e278bc9a01.jpg
│   ├── 6d97739b4a08f965dc9239dd24382e96.jpg
│   ├── 71662d4d4029a3b41d47d5baf681ab9a.jpg
│   ├── 92d90b8977f813af803c78107e7f698e.jpg
│   ├── ad8a37f872956666c3077a3e9e737984.jpg
│   └── df0a3b93e9412536ee8a11255f974141.jpg
├── lib
│   └── mygem.rb
└── spec
    └── _spec.rb
```

The `./images` folder does not really exist until you run `rspec` the first time -- tests do download these binary files from a remote storage, use them and cache them here for later.
There are also rake tasks that use these files and instead of leaving the developer a memo "run this rake task only after you ran rspec" I would like to put the download_and_keep() procedure in some common place callable by both rspec and rake. The question is **what is the recommended place to put such method?**
There is a folder `./spec/support` by rspec design but I'm thinking about switching to minitest so I need something more universal.

P.S.: can't think up more tags for this question.

Comment: I would argue that downloading files in a test is a code smell. IMO requests to the outside should always be stubbed in a test. Furthermore, it seems strange that the test download files and that the user should run rake to do something with these files. Can you please elaborate why you need to download the files? What do rspec and rake do with these files? Why do you need both tools?

Comment: @spickermann, gem does not download anything, so there isn't even anything to stub. Potentially huge binary files are needed for developers to run tests and benchmarks without storing them in git repo. Git LFS is of course is one of possible solutions but it: 1) hard to clean out from git log if you decide to 2) are limited by free quota (this is why I once decided to clean them out but had no success even with official scripts -- quota remained consumed even after they were be removed from the repo history), etc. so I put these files to an external enough reliable file storage.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a standard for such a directory. The important part is to pick a name that, at a glance, doesn't sound like it's supposed to be included in the shipped gem.

For some inspiration, rails/rails has a `tools`, and rubygems/rubygems has `util`. A top-level `support` seems like it'd make a fair choice too.